# C# Swashbuckle Annotations - define response headers

Tags: c#, asp.net, annotations, swagger, swashbuckle

I use annotations like this from the package *Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations* to define responses for swagger:

```
[SwaggerResponse(200, "OK", typeof(SampleResponseClass))]
```

Is it possible with this package to define also the headers of the response? And if not what other possibilities would there be?

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell, there are no pre-existing annotations can be used to describe headers; but you could create your own.

You can create filters that modify the models produces by `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` to enrich the document with additional information. You want to include additional information on an "operation", so you need to implement the `IOperationFilter` interface.

I recommend [checking out the source code](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations/AnnotationsOperationFilter.cs#L74) for `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations` for examples of how you can implement the `IOperationFilter` interface.

Answer (score 1):

I built some Swashbuckle filters a few years ago to support that.

.NET Core:
https://github.com/mattfrear/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters#add-a-response-header

.NET Framework:
https://github.com/mattfrear/Swashbuckle.Examples#add-a-response-header